# Change PostgreSQL CLIENT Ports

Tags: postgresql, connection

I would like to limit PostgreSQL on what ports he allocates for client connections.

What I mean is having the server listening on 5432, when a connection comes in it will allocate a port to that connection, examples currently on my local test server are 61943, 61949, 61951, 61952,  61957, etc.

In a production server what happens is those client ports are around the high 30000s which is a problem since we have some services running on those, sometimes, before our service has a chance to start, a random client connection will steal the port from it.

How would I go about configuring what the client ports should be for PostgreSQL?

Comment: I don't know that you can in PostgreSQL's configuration. It will ask for a free port and the operating system will allocate one. You might be able to do something at the operating-system level though: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15511/how-do-i-reserve-ports-for-my-application

Comment: @RichardHuxton thanks, that did not exactly solve my issue, but going into a suggestion in that thread, I found something that suited, changed net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range so that the range is not inside my services ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have a way to change this, it's up to the Operating System.

If using a unix system you can tell the system not to reserve ports in the range of your application by doing this (x and y being the port numbers):

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="x y"`

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` with your preferred text editor and add `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = x y`

Then to reload the file do `sysctl -p`

This will not kill ongoing connections on the old ports, so a reboot is suggested.